# WSO2 API Manager Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, wso2

so I'm using this repo
https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/simple/am-single/README.md
To deploy WSO2 to an AKS service.
I have my pods setup, as well as services and ingresses.
The thing is I can't access my services.
In the beginning it told me to install the nginx-ingress, I suppose it has something to do with that. If anyone can help me get through this, it would be huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to create an Ingress Controller which allows you to bring traffic into the K8S cluster. You can refer to [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) document. Make sure you follow the AKS-specific section from the document. This will provision IAAS provider-specific infrastructure components that are required along with NginX. After Installing the ingress follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/simple/am-single/README.md#2-obtain-the-external-ip).

Comment: I created the Ingress Controller as required, followed all the steps, 
I still can't get around to launching the WSO2 dashboard on port 9443, I really don't know where to look or how to look for the problem.

Comment: What do you mean can't reach? Have you mapped the DNS to the Public IP?

Comment: That's where I'm stuck at, I don't have a hostname so I'm trying to access using the public IP but I can't reach it.
If I map the DNS to the IP in /etc/host locally, it works, but I can't figure that out on the cluster.

Comment: So your issue is you can access the server when the DNS is mapped in hosts file but not without it?

Comment: Yes, and the thing is I need to access the application from anywhere not just my own pc

Comment: Ok so if your DNS name is abc.com, first you need to purchase that domain through a domain registrar. Then it should be mapped to the public IP of your Ingress. I suppose you can do this using Azure DNS services https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/

Comment: Okay so I get where you're going at, is there any ressource at all for how to get a DNS name through azure, since i looked. Maybe I'm dumb smh

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-getstarted-portal

Comment: Hi @FirasSOLTANI if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I usually hate this kind of "rtm" answer, but it's really not worth doing a duplicata of this great [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-service/) here.

It's worth going through the whole walkthrough even if at some point you figured out what's wrong. You'll learn a lot :)

Comment: I'm kind of out of my field on this one, I know a couple of kubernetes concepts, not going to learn the full debug process overnight and this is my internship, so yeah kind of need help

Comment: Your question is too broad and cannot be answered in that state. Follow that link and when your discover what's wrong then I'll be happy to help you fix up things

Comment: Well what's wrong is that during the HELM installation, the chart takes values for hostname, where you are supposed to map those hostname with an IP (Which is the ingress IP) , I don't have a hostname so it takes the default and I can't map that.
If I map the default hostname to the IP in /etc/hosts it works